# SSL certificate error in windows server 2008 r2

Tags: ssl, certificate, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a valid SSL certificate added to the IIS 6 (windows server 2008 r2) with the following tutorials

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/954755/how-to-configure-intermediate-certificates-on-a-computer-that-is-runni

https://www.trustico.com/install/import/iis7/iis7-pfx-installation.php

I use [IISCrypto](https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto/) and set best practice config with it as you can see
[image: IISCrypto Config GUI]

when I try to browse the website it gives me the following errors in the fire fox and chrome:

Firefox: SSL_ERROR_NO_CYPHER_OVERLAP

Chrome: ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH

I am trying to solve this 4 days :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a conflict with DNS SSL settings like Cloudflare. You need to turn off SSL communication settings or change other settings to resolve your problem.

Comment: There was a security setting on  cloudflare which was set to medium, I set it to low and the problem solved.